# Convergence of a sequence to a point in a set in reflexive Banach space

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, clustering

In the Hilbert space ($\mathcal{H}$) framework, the following Lemma holds:

**Lemma:** Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $\mathcal{H}$ and let $C$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathcal{H}$. Suppose that, for every $x\in C$, $(||x_n-x||)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges and that every weak sequantial cluster point of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ belongs to $C$. Then $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to a point in C.

*Proof:* 
By assumption $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded. A sequence like this converges in $\mathcal{H}$ if and only if it is bounded and possesses at most one weak sequential cluster point. Therefore it is enough to show that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ cannot have two distinct weak sequential cluster point in $C$. To this end, let $x$ and $y$ be weak sequential cluster points of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $C$, say $x_{k_n}\rightharpoonup x$ and $x_{l_n}\rightharpoonup x$. Since $x$ and $y$ belong to $C$, the sequences $(||x_n-x||)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(||x_n-y||)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converge. In turn, since:
$$(\forall n \in \mathbb{N})\quad 2<x_n|x-y>=||x_n-y||^2-||x_n-x||^2+||x||^2+||x||^2-||y||^2$$ 
$(<x_n|x-y>)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges as wel, say $<x_n|x-y>\rightarrow \ell$. Passing to the limit along $(x_{k_n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and along $(x_{l_n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ yields, respectively, $\ell = <x|x-y>=<y|x-y>$. Therefore $||x-y||^2=0$ and hence $x=y$.

---

If the considered space is instead a reflexive Banach space (e.g. the finite dimensional space $(\ell^n_\infty,||\cdot||_\infty)$), is it possible to achieve a similar result? Thank you in advice.

Comment: Why don't you go over the proof and see where does it or does it not cease to work if you only assume reflexivity? Mind you, reflexive Banach spaces are not "namely the finite dimensional space....", as you incorrectly point out.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, unfortunately the proof is related to the inner proof of the Hilbert space used in the Lemma, therefore it is not possible to use a similar demonstration.

Comment: This is a rather narrow point of view. The inner product in Hilbert space is really the action of a bounded linear functional. Thus, to say that "it is not possible to use" lacks imagination, at best.

Comment: I've added the proof of the lemma, it is based on the parallelogram identity that is valid for the Hilbert spaces but not for Banach spaces. That is why I claimed that is not possible to use the same approach. Maybe you can see some ways to perform the proof that I cannot.